# How can I see if a value is present in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to see if there is a way to see if a value is present in an array of objects.

This is my attempt, but it keeps printing false, what would be the most efficient way to approach this problem?

my attempt

```js
var dog_database = [
  {"dog_name": "Joey", "chip_id": "001", "breed": "mixed"},
  {"dog_name": "Max", "chip_id": "002", "breed": "beagle"},
  {"dog_name": "Izzy", "chip_id": "003", "breed": "mixed"},
  {"dog_name": "Frankie", "chip_id": "004", "breed": "terrier"},
  {"dog_name": "Star", "chip_id": "005", "breed": "husky"},
  {"dog_name": "Goku", "chip_id": "006", "breed": "lab"}
];

wanted_value = "mixed";

var isPresent = Object.keys(dog_database).some(function(k) {
  Object.keys(dog_database[k]).some(function(i) {
    if (dog_database[k][i] == wanted_value) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});


console.log(isPresent);
```

Comment: @isherwood Technically, arrays are sort of like objects with `0, 1, 2...` as keys. `Object.keys` gives an array of numbers.

Comment: Fair, but it's not a semantic approach.

Comment: @isherwood Agreed

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the key that holds the value you are looking for is known at runtime? Also calling `keys` on an array is not necessary, you can iterate through it, either with a `for` , `for..of` or `forEach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This want you want?
Use `Array.prototype.some` for checking if a value exists.

```js
var dog_database = [{
    "dog_name": "Joey", "chip_id": "001", "breed": "mixed"
  },
  {
    "dog_name": "Max", "chip_id": "002", "breed": "beagle"
  },
  {
    "dog_name": "Izzy", "chip_id": "003", "breed": "mixed"
  },
  {
    "dog_name": "Frankie", "chip_id": "004", "breed": "terrier"
  },
  {
    "dog_name": "Star", "chip_id": "005", "breed": "husky"
  },
  {
    "dog_name": "Goku", "chip_id": "006", "breed": "lab"
  }
];

wanted_value = "mixed";

var isPresent = dog_database.some(dog => dog.breed === wanted_value)

console.log(isPresent);
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: (I was not the downvoter) For javascript, prefer `===` to `==`, as the latter will attempt to convert the operand types to match, and that conversion may not lead to the expected result. Example: `console.log('1' == 1)` vs `console.log('1' === 1);`

Comment: @Alan it was a typo. fixed now